# Why its always fast to retrieve an object using a number rather than an alphabetic key

Tags: java, collections, hashmap, hashcode, hashset

I was reading `hashcode` and `equals` contract for `HashMap` and `HashSet`. Then I came to know that in `java` we always retrieve every object by their `hash value` (which is a number) in case of HashMap and HashSet etc.. 
I searched it on Google and found that we use hash values(a number) because its faster to retrieve an object than Alphabetic keys, but I could not found any reason why it faster?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you read the wikipedia entry on how hashtables work?

Comment: (And no, the object isn't retrieved by its hash code - that suggests that two keys with the same hash code couldn't be distinguished. In reality, the hash code is used as a first pass to find *candidate* keys. They are then compared using equality comparisons.)